# What is "bci" while debugging in jdb?

Tags: java, debugging, jdb

While debugging with jdb on the command line, it shows me a status line after each step that looks like this:

```
Step completed: "thread=main", [class name].[method], line=10 bci=20
```

What is bci and how can it be useful to me?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

It means `byte code index` . A single line, even a single Java statement, may translate to several bytecode instructions. The byte code index tells you which bytecode instruction was executed.

Comment: I don't quite understand, are you saying that each bci # maps to a specific bytecode instruction (i.e aaload)? Or are you saying that you can tell how many bytecode instructions were run for a certain statement by comparing the deltas between the last two steps?

Comment: @coderrick: each bci maps to a specific bytecode instruction, and from what I can tell the index starts from 0 for each method, as displayed by the javap command.

Comment: Uhhh...I'm sorry but I still can't wrap my head around this. I need an example or a reference. What is instruction 0? When I look at the op-code (bci) reference on Oracle docs or Wikipedia I don't see the instructions in any order. Where can I find more information about this?

Comment: @coderrick: Ahh, we have a misunderstanding. bci is an *index*. bci=0 is the first byte code instruction in a method, bci=1 is the second, etc.

Comment: Okay, but still where could I find more info about this in particular? In addition the jdb tool only has one Oracle doc page that only lists a couple of commands, so I just want few links so I can read up on it.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt Hello, I am a newbie to java, may I ask, what can I do with this bci code? 
Or what did it tell me? 
Thank you

Comment: @时间只会一直走: it would only be relevant if you need to examine the behaviour of code at the level of individual bytecode instructions. Most Java programmers will never need this, probably only people who develop compilers or tools that manipulate bytecode do.

Comment: @MichaelBorgwardt I understand, thank you for your answer.