# How to interpret java kernel traces

Tags: java, trace, vlcj

I'm facing runtime issues with a java application using vlcj.
the file hs_err_pidxxxx.log contains some values I can't interpret:

here is the trace:

```
Current thread (0x00007fa1fcbc5170):  JavaThread "CAM3 PP" daemon [_thread_in_native, id=672224, stack(0x00007fa17beff000,0x00007fa17c000000)]

Stack: [0x00007fa17beff000,0x00007fa17c000000],  sp=0x00007fa17bffd890,  free space=1018k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  [libvlc.so.5.6.1+0x10568]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  uk.co.caprica.vlcj.binding.LibVlc.libvlc_media_player_set_media(Luk/co/caprica/vlcj/binding/internal/libvlc_media_player_t;Luk/co/caprica/vlcj/binding/internal/libvlc_media_t;)V+0
j  uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.base.MediaApi.applyMedia()V+13
j  uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.base.MediaApi.changeMedia(Luk/co/caprica/vlcj/media/Media;)Z+28
j  uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.base.MediaApi.prepare(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Z+10
j  uk.co.caprica.vlcj.player.base.MediaApi.play(Ljava/lang/String;[Ljava/lang/String;)Z+3
j  com.co.project.MediaPane.resetError()V+149
J 11307 c1 com.co.project.MediaPane.NetStatusChanged(Lcom/co/project/tools/NetEvent;)V (84 bytes) @ 0x00007fa2b2303e2c [0x00007fa2b2303700+0x000000000000072c]
J 11257 c1 com.co.project.tools.Poller.fireNetEvent(Lcom/co/project/tools/NetEvent;)V (45 bytes) @ 0x00007fa2b22ecf74 [0x00007fa2b22ecce0+0x0000000000000294]
j  com.co.project.tools.Poller.run()V+258
j  java.lang.Thread.run()V+11 java.base@17.0.6
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

siginfo: si_signo: 11 (SIGSEGV), si_code: 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), si_addr: 0x0000000000000000
```

I interpret the line

```
j  com.co.project.MediaPane.resetError()V+149
```

as interpreted code, method resetError() returns void

What I'm missing is what +149 mean in this context. In my "normal" stacktrace I find there the line number but it doesn't seems to be the case.

Comment: That number seems to be the [byte code index (bci)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7660673/what-is-bci-while-debugging-in-jdb). The link explains what it is - I couldn't find any authoritative definition yet but [this](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2013/02/analysing-a-java-core-dump.html)  indicates the number is the bci: dump contains `j  CoreDumper.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+7` -> jstack analysis contains `- CoreDumper.main(java.lang.String[]) @bci=7, line=12 (Interpreted frame)
`